# Проблемы с кодировкой в ответе геокодера

Tags: php, json, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api, geocode

Пытаюсь получить координаты по названию объекта в формате JSON, но в ответе геокодера вместо названия объекта набор символов.
Раньше код работал, но недавно в Яндексе изменились требования и начались проблемы.
техподдержка Яндекс говорит что теперь геокодер принимает только UTF-8 кодировку. Ок, настроил сервер, и внутреннюю кодировку на UTF-8. Для запроса координат, например, Санкт-Петербурга в ответ прилетает это Ð¡Ð°Ð½ÐºÑ-ÐÐµÑÐµÑÐ±ÑÑÐ³. В таком формате:

```
array(1) { ["response"]=> array(1) { ["GeoObjectCollection"]=> array(2) { ["metaDataProperty"]=> array(1) { ["GeocoderResponseMetaData"]=> array(3) { ["request"]=> string(57) "Ð¡Ð°Ð½ÐºÑ-ÐÐµÑÐµÑÐ±ÑÑÐ³" ["results"]=> string(2) "10" ["found"]=> string(1) "0" } } ["featureMember"]=> array(0) { } } } }
```

Тестовый код:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output ('UTF-8');
mb_http_input ('UTF-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$user_2 = "Санкт-Петербург";
$url = 'https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=c910121a-bfc1-479e-a7d1-xxx&geocode='.$user_2;
$ar = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
$coords = $ar['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']['GeoObject']['Point']['pos'];
list($lon,$lat) = explode(' ',$coords);
$lon = +$lon;
$lat = +$lat;
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Кодировка переменной 'user_2': ");
echo mb_detect_encoding($user_2);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Содержимое переменной 'user_2': ");
print_r ($user_2);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Кодировка сформированного запроса для геокодера: ");
echo mb_detect_encoding($url);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Вид запроса для геокодера: ");
print_r ($url);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Кодировка данных, полученных от геокодера: ");
echo mb_detect_encoding($ar['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderResponseMetaData']['request']);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Содержимое массива: ");
var_dump ($ar);
```

Результат выполнения кода:

```
Notice: Undefined index: GeoObject in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testData.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testData.php on line 12

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testData.php on line 13


Кодировка переменной 'user_2': UTF-8

Содержимое переменной 'user_2': Санкт-Петербург

Кодировка сформированного запроса для геокодера: UTF-8

Вид запроса для геокодера: https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=c910121a-bfc1-479e-a7d1-xxx&geocode=Санкт-Петербург

Кодировка данных, полученных от геокодера: UTF-8

Содержимое массива: array(1) { ["response"]=> array(1) { ["GeoObjectCollection"]=> array(2) { ["metaDataProperty"]=> array(1) { ["GeocoderResponseMetaData"]=> array(3) { ["request"]=> string(57) "Ð¡Ð°Ð½ÐºÑ-ÐÐµÑÐµÑÐ±ÑÑÐ³" ["results"]=> string(2) "10" ["found"]=> string(1) "0" } } ["featureMember"]=> array(0) { } } } }
```

Кто подскажет как правильно кодировать запрос для геокодера?
Видно что запрос сформирован в UTF-8, ответ тоже получен в UTF-8 но при этом в виде кракозябр. Сторонние кодировщики говорят что значение в массиве в кодировке ISO-8859-1, но я как понимаю ISO-8859-1 полностью совместима с UTF-8.

Comment: Такая же проблема возникла при отправке запроса из 1С. Отправляем текст в UTF-8. В ответе кракозябры.

Comment: +1. Написал в поддержку, добавил ссылку на этот вопрос, может ответят

Comment: @Станислав , а закодировать текст перед отправкой запроса не помогает?
**$url = 'https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=c910121a-bfc1-479e-a7d1-xxx&geocode='.urlencode($user_2);**

Answer (score 0):

В результате выполнения, видно что проблема в строке 11, в массиве нет ключа `GeoObject`

попробуйте так:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$user_2 = "Санкт-Петербург";
$url = 'https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=c910121a-bfc1-479e-a7d1-xxx&geocode=' . $user_2;
$ar = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$coords = getRawCoords($ar);
if (empty($coords)) {
    var_dump($ar);
}
list($lon, $lat) = explode(' ', $coords);
$lon = +$lon;
$lat = +$lat;
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Кодировка переменной 'user_2': ");
echo mb_detect_encoding($user_2);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Содержимое переменной 'user_2': ");
print_r($user_2);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Кодировка сформированного запроса для геокодера: ");
echo mb_detect_encoding($url);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Вид запроса для геокодера: ");
print_r($url);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Кодировка данных, полученных от геокодера: ");
echo mb_detect_encoding($ar['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderResponseMetaData']['request']);
echo "</br></br>";
print_r("Содержимое массива: ");
var_dump($ar);

function getRawCoords(array $response)
{
    switch (true) {
        case !isset($response['response']):
        case !isset($response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']):
        case !isset($response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']):
        case !isset($response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']['GeoObject']):
        case !isset($response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']['GeoObject']['Point']):
        case !isset($response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']['GeoObject']['Point']['pos']):
            return null;
        default:
            return $response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']['GeoObject']['Point']['pos'];
    }
}
```

Таким образом, вы поймете, что за ошибка возвращается вам

Comment: То, что в массиве нет ключа это понятно. Его нет как раз из-за того, что в request попадает этот набор символов. Если в поисковой строке браузера вставить запрос с такими же корявыми символами, то ```GeoObject```  тоже не будет.   Если разобраться кто "портит" кодировку, то все встанет на свои места. Но тут интересная штука: у меня все настроено на UTF-8, яндекс говорит что тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулась с такой же проблемой, сервер на Tomcat.
Изменение кодировки в Tomcate решило проблему:

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно экранировать текст запроса функцией urlencode().
В Вашем конкретном случае нужно экранировать переменную $user_2.